# Slowdown on SO and meta?

Tags: discussion, performance, outage

Is anyone else seeing SO and meta responding very slowly when clicking links, etc?  I thought perhaps it was issues with my ISP at home, but I'm seeing the same sort of problems at work.  Periodically it will take a few seconds when I click on a link to get a response.  It seems to have started after yesterday's SO outage.

**EDIT**: Right now I can't seem to connect to SO at all.  [Downforeveryorjustme.com](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) reports SO is out for everyone.

**EDIT2**: Seems back up now... I won't keep updating if it goes down again, though.  Hope @Jeff posts something on his blog about why this is happening.

Comment: Yeah it seems to go up and down for me at the moment.

Comment: Meta has been fine for me, SO has been hit & miss.

Comment: SO was completely wedged when I tried to load it a few minutes back... Now it's reasonably responsive.

Comment: Confirmed, although I have the feeling it's acutally sstatic.net that's acting up.

Comment: @balpha: That hasn't matched with my experience of it today (fwiw). That's been the problem any number of *other* times, but not (for me) today.

Comment: This is getting **really** irritating.

Comment: Confirm, SO is slow here as well.

Comment: Maybe that would explain why there is less activity on meta

Comment: Just took too long for your molecules to shift back into phase.

Comment: @Downvoter - yeah, it's Friday (here and in Iceland) and not much activity.  I'm still seeing slowdown on meta, but it's intermittent.

Comment: Things appear back to normal from here.

Comment: Same here, SO was extremely slow all day but is fine now. This is the first time it *wasn't* ads.stackoverflow.com nor any other contributing domain (I think) but the site itself. (Germany)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Last night we made a change to our network to the goal of simplifying our configuration.  We have removed TProxy from our HAProxy servers and are now using X-Forwarded-For headers to track IPs.  We also removed the IIS7 dynamic IP restrictions module from the IIS instances and are now using iptables / netfilter to control rate limiting.  The default maximum number of connections that are tracked for iptables / netfilter is 32764 which we hit at around 5:00am PST.  I bumped up this value to 65528 which solved the latency issues.  We will continue to keep an eye on it.

Comment: Hah! Tech-talk to confuse the audience!

Comment: Isn't 65k very low? Why not set it to 200k so you won't run again into this problem relatively soon?

Comment: @Kop. I don't think the servers would handle 200k simultaneous connections being processed at the same time.. or at least not with any speed..

Answer (score 9):

[image: oh noes!]
<sub>(source: [borev.net](https://www.borev.net/ohnoes.jpg))</sub>

**I might have to actually do work today...**